# Scrapy Splash Screenshot Pipeline not working

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to save screenshots of scraped webpages with Scrapy Splash. I've copied and pasted the code found here into my pipeline folder: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Here's the code from the url:

```
import scrapy
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import quote


class ScreenshotPipeline(object):
    """Pipeline that uses Splash to render screenshot of
    every Scrapy item."""

    SPLASH_URL = "http://localhost:8050/render.png?url={}"

    async def process_item(self, item, spider):
        encoded_item_url = quote(item["url"])
        screenshot_url = self.SPLASH_URL.format(encoded_item_url)
        request = scrapy.Request(screenshot_url)
        response = await spider.crawler.engine.download(request, spider)

        if response.status != 200:
            # Error happened, return item.
            return item

        # Save screenshot to file, filename will be hash of url.
        url = item["url"]
        url_hash = hashlib.md5(url.encode("utf8")).hexdigest()
        filename = "{}.png".format(url_hash)
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        # Store filename in item.
        item["screenshot_filename"] = filename
        return item
```

I've also followed the instructions for setting up splash found here: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

When I call the command `scrapy crawl spider`everything works correctly except the pipeline. 
This is the "Error" I'm seeing.

```
<coroutine object ScreenshotPipeline.process_item at 0x7f29a9c7c8c0>
```

The spider is yielding the item correctly, but it will not process the item.

Does anyone have any advice? Thank you.

Edit:

I think what is going on is that Scrapy is calling the process_item() method as you normally would. However according to these docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html a coroutine object must be called differently.

asyncio.run(process_item()) rather than process_item().
I think I may have to modify the source code?

Comment: Coroutine support in Scrapy is recent and limited, make sure you read https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/coroutines.html

Comment: Did you use a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

You should use scrapy-splash in a script inside spider not in the pipelines.

I followed this [docs](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-splash/) and it works for me.